# PHP time to Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Hi i'm using php5 and mysql.
I have a time like that 10:00, 10:45 ... and i shoult put it a mysql database in form 'hh:mm:ss'
I tryed in different way but nothing works.
What i try was:

```
$time= time('H:i:s', $mytime)
$time= time('H:i:s', strtotime($mytime))
$time= strtotime($mytime)
$time= strtotime($mytime.':00')
```

Comment: "nothing works" explains nothing. And there is nothing related to the mysql in your code

Comment: What do you get into your database?  what is does your insert look like?

Comment: Please show your database schema, you can try to insert any way you want but if your schema does not allow for that particular format, no matter what you do, it will not structure as `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Insert in a database works correctly. I insert data correctly for the other attributes and not in the time. Mysql want time format like H:m:s but I have time like a string in format hh:mm. When I insert data in database everything is correct exept time that is 00:00:00 so my format of time si incorrect. How can i change my format time to the correct one?

Comment: At the end I didn't use TIME but DATETIME like sum of a date and a time

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO table SET `time`='$mytime';
```

Hint: be sure you are using proper Mysql field format

Another hint: do not use randomly picked PHP functions. At least try to read the function description in the manual. It can give you idea if this function suit your needs or not.

Answer (score -1):

strtotime need a complete date as input and outputs an int. You don't need an int for mysql, you only need the string you have plus the seconds info:

```
$time = $mytime.':00';
```

Then insert time in db, as @Your_Common_Sense says, you need to user TIME datatype in order to insert a time in this format.